# Differentiability of functions on Manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, submanifold

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ be smooth, and suppose $M$ and $N$ are submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$. Moreover, assume that $f(M) \subseteq N$. I want to prove that $f:M\to N$ is differentiable.

The outline of my proof is that since $M$ and $N$ are submanifolds $\exists$ charts $(W_1,G_1)$ at $x \in M$ and $(W_2,G_2)$ at $f(x) \in N$ and the map $G_2^{-1} \circ F \circ G_1: W_1 \to W_2$ is differentiable (because $F$ is smooth and $G_1$ and $G_2$ are homeomorphic).

Did I miss anything? 
I appreciate it if someone can evaluate my proof. Thanks.

Comment: You should edit your question - you have to  assume $f(M) \subset N$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Thank you. I revised the question.

Comment: In your attempt, you just wrote what it means for $f$ to be differentiable, but you didn't prove anything. Hint: $f|_M = f\circ i$ where $i:M\to \Bbb R^n$ the inclusion. Check that $i$ is smooth and that the composition of smooth maps is smooth.

Comment: @IvoTerek . Thanks! It is now more clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use charts $(W_1,G_1)$ at $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $(W_2,G_2)$ at $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}^m$ where

(1) $W_1$ is an open neighborhood of $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $G_1 : W_1 \to U_1$ is a diffeomorphism onto an open $U_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $G_1(W_1 \cap M) = U_1 \cap \mathbb{R}^k \times \lbrace 0 \rbrace$.

(1) $W_2$ is an open neighborhood of $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $G_2 : W_2 \to U_2$ is a diffeomorphism onto an open $U_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $G_2(W_2 \cap N) = U_2 \cap \mathbb{R}^l \times \lbrace 0 \rbrace$.

This produces charts $G_1' : W_1' = W_1 \cap M \to U_1' \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ and $G_2' : W_2' =  W_2 \cap N \to U_2' \subset \mathbb{R}^l$ which allow to deduce that $f : M \to N$ is smooth around $x \in M$.

By the way, it is known that the inclusion $i : M \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is smooth so that $f \mid_M : M \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is automatically smooth.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please explain why $G_1(W_1 \cap M) = U_1 \cap \mathbb{R}^k \times \{ 0 \}$? Shouldn't be just $G_1(W_1 \cap M) = U_1$. I do not understand why we have that .

Comment: This is the definition of a submanifold. If $P$ is an $n$-manifold, then $M \subset P$ is a $k$-dimensional submanifold if for each $x \in M$ there exists a chart $(W,G : W \to U)$ for $P$ such that $W$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ in $P$, $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open $G(W \cap M) = U \cap \mathbb{R}^k \times \lbrace 0 \rbrace$. If you regard $W$ as a manifold (this can be done by using the atlas having only one chart $(W,G)$), then $G$ becomes a diffeomorphism. Let $U' \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ be the open set such that $U' \times  \lbrace 0 \rbrace = $

Comment: $U \cap \mathbb{R}^k \times \lbrace 0 \rbrace$, then you get a chart $G' : W \cap M \to U'$ for $M$.

Comment: Thank you for your response.